# Swift Syntax for Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Obj C I created a property

```
@property(nonatomic) UILabel *subscriptionText;
```

Then I created a setter method for that property UILabel. like below

```
-(UILabel *)subscriptionText{
    if (!_subscriptionText) {
        _subscriptionText = [UILabel new];
        _subscriptionText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   _subscriptionText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;


    }
    return _subscriptionText;
}
```

then In viewdidload I add this view by

```
[self.view addSubview:self.subscriptionText];
```

How can I do this same scenario in Swift 4.2.

Comment: `-(UILabel *)subscriptionText;` is a getter method.

Comment: In Swift Bro I am Asking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *lazy* initialization is what you need.

```
lazy var subscriptionText: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .justified

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(subscriptionLabel)

    // Label constraints
}
```